# Outputting information after provisioning a vm with terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have a set of vm instance I want to provision with terraform.

Each VM will need the information from the previous one in the chain - during setup a unique key is created for a peering app.

Thoughts about the approach:

- read the information from (write to disk) and put it as the single page of a simple web server
- output something using local-exec, remote-exec
- Something else?

That is to say, I need non-standard (where standard is something like an IP address, hostname) output by a service started after provisioning, that I can then pass to later provisioners. It's getting the output that is the issue, not the dependency.

Comment: We had similar challenges in validating hardening scores of newly created images. We tried to use `local-exec`, `remote-exec` but they appeared to be ugly. Fortunately, the logs of the service we want to analyze are pushed to a centralized logging server, so terraform would query that logging server via restapi & fetch results. If you have such logging server, you get benefited. Otherwise, local-exec/remote-exec..

Comment: Also, you can write a tiny plugin of your own analyse the file or output you are interested. I wrote such tiny plugin to fetch ip of the machine running terraform.

Comment: oh, this seems really interesting (the plug-in) - any chance you have publication around that?

Comment: How are you executing the software provisioning for the "unique key"?

Comment: It was derived from [this](https://github.com/kekwork/terraform-provider-ip) repo. This provider queries a third party website & returns the public ip. If the requests are NATed in between, you get a different ip. I did tweak a bit to fetch the local ip without querying the third party service. If you are really interested, I can try publishing it to public registry..

Comment: @MattSchuchard very similar to this - https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/join-nodes/ - the service generates a token that gets used later

Answer (score 0):

Terraform has in built functionality to maintain dependencies.

Perhaps you can create the keys as separate resources, and then reference them in both linked vm's ?

Or if not maybe the key that is created can be exported in TF ? Then you can reference it in another VM resource, and TF will be smart enough to first build the first one, then the second.

There probably is a TF solution for your problem, without having to hack around too much. Already local-exec is a last resort kind of thing.

Comment: Tried to clarify - it's less about the provisioning, and more about getting the output of earlier service start, for later use.

Comment: Seems like a bit of an antipattern for TF. Can you first provision the macines, and then run something to configure them like an ansible workbook ?

Comment: i could but this feels terrible - adding an entirely different framework just to get a single line of config feels like picking up a ton of debt

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I ended up stripping all the provisioners out of the terraform, and just built a simple script, the first step of which was to execute the terraform apply, and then did the rest with simple remote script execution over ssh. Ugly, but it worked.

Comment: [ssh_resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/loafoe/ssh/latest/docs/resources/resource) could do these for you?

Comment: SIGH. Holy cow that's amazing - didn't even know about it.

Comment: Me neither until recently. Let me know if this work for you..